# Display not working after computer was turned to sleep

Tags: laptop, display, motherboard, sleep

I have a laptop with a brand new motherboard. (I have to mention this for later on)

One day, I put it on sleep so I can resume my work in no-time. As soon as I turned it on, the screen was black, no backlight, no image, no nothing (tested it from every corner possible to check what's wrong).

I sent it to repair shop and they said the motherboard is faulty, although I can use an external monitor with it and there is no issue at all.

Whenever I lift the laptop screen, it detects it as 2 monitors being on.

Anyone can explain how can this happen? Can the motherboard be faulty already?

Answer (score 0):

The motherboard will still conserve it's features even when failing, that's why your system detects the 2nd display but it's not working. You can disable the display on device manager or set it up to always "duplicate" screen (this may give you a wrong resolution for the external monitor).
I would send the notebook to the brand official support center.

Comment: It works with an external display. I sent it to the support center, but they said the graphics output for the display is faulty. A complete change of the motherboard isn't worth it for this old laptop, and the repair costs just as much.